# jquery dynamic $.post

Tags: jquery

I have a list of checkboxes generated dynamically. Exp:

```
<input class="cb1" var1="1" var2="2" var3="3" type="checkbox" /><label>Checkbox1</label>
```

I am trying to $.post values of 'var1', 'var2' and 'var3' to a php file 'data.php' for each checkbox that is checked.

I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Also correct the syntax of the input tag, It has no var1="1" etc properties. It has a value property.

Answer (score 1):

you can use $('#form').serialize() if you want to serialize all form element, but in your case, you can use $().find() function to scan generated checkbox, and use $.each to iterate each element found

assume that your checkbox remain in your div with id='checkbox_conrainter', and it has name attribute 'checkbox[]'

```
<div id="checkbox_container">
    <input name="checkbox[]" class="cb1" var1="1" var2="2" var3="3" type="checkbox" /><label>Checkbox1</label>
    <input name="checkbox[]" class="cb2" var1="1" var2="2" var3="3" type="checkbox" /><label>Checkbox2</label>
</div>
```

on javascript section you can write:

```
 var $postData = '';
 $('#checkbox_conrainter').find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
    var $checkbox = $(this); //just for object caching
    if($checkbox).is(':checked')){
        var $checkbox_name = $checkbox.attr('name');
        var $checkbox_val1 = $checkbox.attr('val1'); //you can use loop if you want
        var $checkbox_val2 = $checkbox.attr('val2');
        var $checkbox_val3 = $checkbox.attr('val3');
    }
    $postData +='&'+$checkbox_name+'[val1]='+$checkbox_val1
               +'&'+$checkbox_name+'[val2]='+$checkbox_val2
               +'&'+$checkbox_name+'[val3]='+$checkbox_val3;
});
$.post('data.php',$postData);
```

in your php page, the structure of the variable will be like this

```
$_POST = Array(
    checkbox[0] => Array(
        [val1] => 1 //val1 value,
        [val2] => 2 //val2 value,
        [val3] => 3 //val3 value
    ),
    checkbox[1] => Array(  //if you have more checkbox
        [val1] => 1 //val1 value,
        [val2] => 2 //val2 value,
        [val3] => 3 //val3 value
    ),
)
```

cmiiw

Answer (score 0):

First of all enclose all check boxes in a  tag with id or name property.

Then on any event or button click you can put the values by

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#input_form").submit(function(){
                 var querystring = $(this).serialize();
                   $.ajax({
                   type: 'POST',
                   url: url,
                   data: querystring,
                   success: success,
                         dataType: dataType
                     });
                 });
        });
```

and in PHP file try to get the values in loop

```
        foreach($_POST as $val){
             //TODO make a query string again for inserting in db etc
        }
```

Comment: I can't use a form. I am trying to do something like this: $('.cb1').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
         {
          var1 = $(this).attr('var1')
         }
        alert(var1);